# Excel Why is my IF-formula not working?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I have this formula:

```
=IF(testing!I:I=A6;testing!A:A;"wrong")
```

I want to control with the formula whether the mapping of values is right.
I want to know whether the value in A6 has more corresponding values in the column A in the 'testing'-sheet. So when A6 appears in the column I, I either want to know which corresponding value it has in column A, OR if he has MORE THAN ONE, I want to get 'wrong' as an answer.

Comment: I ONLY want to have 'wrong', when the value in A& has more than ONE corresponding value in the columns A. Yet, I get 'wrong' even though I checked and some of them have only ONE corresponding value, so that the result should be the corresponding value and NOT 'wrong' :( @pnuts

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because if you simplify the test to just `=I:I=A6` that will always return `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes that might be the problem. Unfortunately I don't get it how I can adapt it. Do you have an idea? @pnuts

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @pnuts, you did not offer a solution and simply changing that part of the formula would in no way solve his problem.

Answer (score -2):

## Code:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(testing!I:I,A6)=1,INDEX(testing!A:A,MATCH(A6,testing!I:I,0)),"Wrong")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is already better than mine. I get way more corresponding values than with my initial formula. But there are some cells where I get '0' even though there should be a corresponding value. Do you know why??? @jbarker2160

Comment: If it is blank, the formula will return 0.

Comment: @question, did you use the formula posted above exactly? It should work for you in every case.  Also, if it works, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yes I used exactly your formula. I still get wrong even though there should only be ONE corresponding value :( Do you know what the problem is? @pnuts

Comment: Yes I used exactly your formula. I still get wrong even though there should only be ONE corresponding value :( Do you know what the problem is? @jbarker2160