# Excel How can I get my formula working?

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, formula

I have this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(testing!I:I,A6)=1,INDEX(testing!A:A,MATCH(A5,testing!I:I,0)),"wrong")
```

I want to control with the formula whether the mapping of values is right.
I want to know whether the value in `A6` has more corresponding values in the column `A` in the `testing` sheet. So when `A6` appears in the column `I`, I either want to know which corresponding value it has in column `A`, OR if he has MORE THAN ONE, I want to get `wrong` as an answer.

Currently there are still many cells with wrong even though it actually has only ONE corresponding value. WHY?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Why is my IF-formula not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121705/excel-why-is-my-if-formula-not-working)

Comment: yes it's a duplicate, but I still have no working answert :( @jbarker2160

Comment: Are you sure that the data is exactly the same?  Check for spaces before and after the values in both columns, but without actually seeing the data it'll be very difficult to help.

Comment: I have, there are no spaces. And you can't see an obvious mistake right away? :/ I need to get an answer today, therefore I'm glad about every recommendation. @jbarker2160

Answer (score 1):

You are counting `A6`, but matching `A5`. Both should be the same.

Comment: Ah that's wrong, sorry. I have it right in my excel sheet. The formula I'm talking about is this one: =IF(COUNTIF(testing!I:I,A6)=1,INDEX(testing!A:A,MATCH(A6,testing!I:I,0)),"wrong")  @jbarker2160